# editortype, collaborator for inproceedings

Tags: biblatex

I can not get "in collaboration with" for @ inproceedings entry because it concerns the work and not the article as I would.

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{roure07,
  author = {Réjane Roure},
  title = {Armes et têtes coupées au Cailar (Gard): premier éléments de réflexion
    sur un dépôts rituel en Gaule méditerranéenne},
  booktitle = {L'âge du Fer dans l'arc jurassien et ses marges : dépôts, lieux sacrés
    et territorialité à l'âge du Fer : actes du XXIX\ieme{} colloque
    international de l'AFEAF, volume 2},
  year = {2007},
  editor = {{\relax Ph}ilippe Barral and Alain Daubigney and Cynthia Dunning
    and Gilbert Kaenel and Marie-Jeanne Roulière-Lambert},
  pages = {653-658},
  address = {Besançon},
  publisher = {Presses universitaires de Franche-Comté},
  editora = {Henri Duday},
  editoratype = {collaborator},
  eventdate = {2005-05},
  owner = {Axel},
  timestamp = {2014.03.06},
  venue = {Bienne}
}
```

A beautiful screenshot will be more understandable than my ridiculous english [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}                                                        %type de document+ police
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
%\setmonofont[Scale=0.75]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Bonnes notes, sans exposant.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \noindent\makebox[2em][r]{\@thefnmark.\space}#1}
\makeatother



\usepackage{microtype}  %gère la microtypo
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{shorttoc}

%%% MARGES ET INTERLIGNES
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper}
    \geometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm , right=2cm}

                                    %gestion interligne                                                     
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing                                                                                         % interligne 1.5
\let\oldquotation\quotation                                                                     %Rédéfinit l'environnement quotation pour avoir un interligne de 1
\let\endoldquotation\endquotation
\renewenvironment{quotation}
{\begin{oldquotation}\singlespace}
 {\end{oldquotation}}

%MACRO
\newcommand\cad{c’est-à-dire}
\newcommand\than{« temps d'Hannibal »}
\newcommand\avjc{av. J.-C.}
\newcommand\apjc{apr. J.-C.}
\newcommand\cnrs{C.N.R.S.}
\newcommand\dgp{deuxième guerre punique}
\providecommand{\ier}{\textsuperscript{er}}
\providecommand{\iers}{\textsuperscript{ers}}
\providecommand{\iere}{\textsuperscript{ère}}
\providecommand{\ieres}{\textsuperscript{ères}}
\providecommand{\ieme}{\textsuperscript{e}}
\providecommand{\iemes}{\textsuperscript{es}}
\providecommand{\nd}{\textsuperscript{nd}}
\providecommand{\nds}{\textsuperscript{nds}}
\providecommand{\nde}{\textsuperscript{nde}}
\providecommand{\ndes}{\textsuperscript{ndes}}
\providecommand{\no}{\textsuperscript{o}}
\providecommand{\nos}{\textsuperscript{os}}

\providecommand{\mme}{M\textsuperscript{me}\space}
\providecommand{\mmes}{M\textsuperscript{mes}\space}
\providecommand{\mr}{M.\space}
\providecommand{\mrs}{MM.\space}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %BILIOGRAPHIE  

\usepackage[                                                                                                                %BILIOGRAPHIE
  backend=bibtex,%
  language=french,%
  style=authoryear,%
firstinits,%
   mergedate=false,%
   style=authoryear-ibid,%
   maxcitenames=2, %
   maxbibnames=999,%
]{biblatex} 

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{(#4)}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{(#3)}{#5}{#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space}      %tiret après le label
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%                                          rajoute date





\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1} 
  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                                 enlève guillemets articles
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace\addcolon\space}}

  %Met les abréviations des revues
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {%
      \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
        {}
        {%
          \printtext[journaltitle]
            {%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
              \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
             }%
         }%
    }
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
}

%Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extraalpha}}
\makeatother
% "Et al." en ITALIQUE

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

 %%% Histoire des noms    et al...
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{##1}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
\makeatother
    %minuscule citation
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}}                 
%Enlève parenthèse colloque
\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{                        
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {%
      \bibstring{presentedat}%
      \printfield{eventtitle}%
    }%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext{%
       \printfield{venue}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printeventdate}}%
  \newunit
}


    \DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
 byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}%                         
 {Établit\space par}%
{dir\adddotspace\smartof}, 
in = {\textit{in}},%
 editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
 editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
 opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
idem = {\emph{idem}},%
ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
%pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
 %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
}
%enlève la virugule avant dir.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
    \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
%     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
     \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

 %%modifié book pour virgule
 \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

  %Change ordre des entrées pour les in quelquechoses : 
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
 \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldequalstr{edition}{1}
    {\clearfield{edition}}
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{proceedings}} or test {\ifentrytype{incollection}} }
       {\savefield*{edition}{\savededition}%
        \clearfield{edition}}
       {}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection]{pages}{pp\adddotspace #1}%


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

Comment: So: Duday is not a 'second' author for this paper, but a mere(?) collaborator?  It sounds like you're going to need to add a non-basic field for `editortype`.  Can you provide  [*un exemple complet minimal*](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: @ Axelito I have updated my answer in the light of your additions. It would generally be helpful if you could try to edit down the example so that it is (a) a complete and compilable document and (b) as small as possible, though I appreciate that is difficult when you have such an extensively modified style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caveat: I think you are using a fairly home-brewed style, which makes modifications awkward, and this is not fully tested, except on your sample `.bib`. I can see that some things (like the `bibstrings` you've used for editors) are not the same, but I *hope* the solution I have will work with your style, since it involves modifying a macro that I'm guessing you haven't touched -- or if you have you will be able to adapt it.

The standard Biblatex styles all assume that `editora` etc are associated with the journal or book, not the article, as you observe. The way these things are typeset is bound up in a particularly nicely knotted up set of macros, which I don't like to fiddle with. So there are at least two sensible ways forward:

1. Modify the `inproceedings` driver, to check for an `editora` (or what have you) and deal with it first.
2. Hack the *author* macro, so that it does the work.

Not having access to your modified drivers, I've done the second. To use this you need to put the relevant person in the `namea` field, and the relevant "role" in the `nameatype` field. I decided (arbitrarily perhaps) to prevent dashes being used if there is a collaborator (since it would be ambiguous as to whether the author was the same or both were the same, and I don't know how to hash both: a real expert might know, but it's unlikely to matter).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{roure07,
  author = {Réjane Roure},
  title = {Armes et têtes coupées au Cailar (Gard): premier éléments de réflexion
    sur un dépôts rituel en Gaule méditerranéenne},
  booktitle = {L'âge du Fer dans l'arc jurassien et ses marges : dépôts, lieux sacrés
    et territorialité à l'âge du Fer : actes du XXIX\ieme{} colloque
    international de l'AFEAF, volume 2},
  year = {2007},
  editor = {{\relax Ph}ilippe Barral and Alain Daubigney and Cynthia Dunning
    and Gilbert Kaenel and Marie-Jeanne Roulière-Lambert},
  pages = {653-658},
  address = {Besançon},
  publisher = {Presses universitaires de Franche-Comté},
  namea = {Henri Duday},
  nameatype = {collaborator},
  eventdate = {2005-05},
  owner = {Axel},
  timestamp = {2014.03.06},
  venue = {Bienne}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \ifnameundef{namea}
         {}
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
          \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
          \setunit{\addspace}%
          \printnames{namea}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{nameatype}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of output]

---

**UPDATE**

In view of your various modifications (which almost amount to a new style!) I would approach things differently, though still putting the collaborator into the `namea` field, and the type in the `nameatype` field.

We define two new `bibmacros` to format the `namea` field.

```
 \newbibmacro{nameaname}{%
   \ifnameundef{namea}
     {}
     {\usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
      \printnames{namea}}}

 \newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
   \iffieldundef{nameatype}
     {}
     {\setunit{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
```

We then modify the `inproceedings` driver to use the `namea` macro immediately after printing the author.

```
  ...
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \usebibmacro{nameaname}%<--ADDED
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  ...
```

(You might want to do that with `incollection` and `inbook` too, if needed.)

Producing the result:

[image: revised results]

On this occasion I haven't (as I originally did) modified the hashing to prevent the use of a dash for a repeated author, but you could easily add that to the `nameaname` macro if you wanted to.